# Windows 10: Can You Have a OS / Data Drive Separation?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I tried changing an HDD on my Alienware and it was not recognized by windows 10. I read somewhere you cannot change the drive unless you reinstall windows 10...

I also just formatted the OS drive and it did not recognize the partitions on the data drive (I did pick the advanced option in the installation, but still) -- which were created by win 10! -- it forced them to be formatted! Strangely I did not have these issues with my other (data) SSD.

Is it possible to maintain the data in a data drive while reinstalling windows 10, and also, is it possible to change the HDD with windows 10?

Comment: You move you Documents,My Music, and etc  to another drive relatively easy.  Its moving the OS or installed programs where it gets complex.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the OS drive in Windows 10. Numerous 'cloning' programs allow a drive's contents to be copied to a new drive, which can replace the old drive.  It can be done.  Which apps will do that and which will create a bootable drive is a subject for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

As to 'data' drives, that gets somewhat complex.  By default, [Windows itself stores much data on the OS drive](http://ask-leo.com/why_is_my_c_drive_filling_up_even_though_i_install_programs_on_d.html), [even if you designate a different 'data' drive](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/changing-default-save-location-reverts-back-to-c/b82778d9-322f-4fea-a53b-ff0d5eeeffb9) for 'My Documents', 'My Music', 'My Videos', et al. Following this dubious trend, many apps also default to using the OS drive, even if you wish to install them to a different drive, and will expect to store data on the OS drive.

Comment: I am talking about my own data files in 'Data'. What is the difference between changing the OS drive or a Data drive? it is the same problem.

Comment: By default, Windows itself stores much data on the OS drive, even if you designate a different 'data' drive for 'My Documents', 'My Music', 'My Videos', et al.; see C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\  . Many apps will also store data on the OS drive even if installed to D:. See links above for detail.